# facebook comments "source"

Tags: api, facebook

I have an IFrame app and some pages in app have fb comments plugin.

If users check `Post to Profile` box, it puts a post on his wall:

[image: wall post screenshot]

Is there s way to remove the `Source:` item?

Here is the code:

```
<fb:comments
    xid="image_id"
    url='url_for_like_button'
    title="Comments box title"
    showform="true"
    simple="1"
    >
</fb:comments>
```

Comment: A screenshot of what you're seeing would be helpful.

Comment: added screenshot of wall post to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Facebook provide the API with the ability to do that. It's useful for us end users to identify if a status update is from a real person, or spam...

Answer (score 0):

you cannot remove the URL but can change it keeping the same domain something like this:
`<fb:comments 
      publish_feed='0'
      expr:title='data:post.title' 
      **url='http://www.changedsource.com'**
      simple="1" 
      publish_feed="false" 
      width='300px' 
      canpost="true" 
candelete="0" />`